# I need guidance regarding a permutation based distribution problem

Tags: statistical-significance, spatial, permutation-test

I am conducting a semester project that involves evaluating proportions of landcover (from NLCD) within animal survey areas (1km grid cells). A professor suggested that I randomly sample proportion of land cover in grid cells about 10,000 times, and then use permutation based distributions to see if the observed land cover proportions in the survey grids are randomly distributed, or if they are significantly bias.

I understand the idea behind this process, but I do not know where to begin with randomly sampling grid cells 10,000 times, and I do not know how to perform a permutation distribution test.
Working in RStudio and ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: I suggest exploring the following tools in ArcGIS: `Generate Tesselation` and `Create Random Points`.

Comment: There are significant missing details here. If the plot you are dealing with is *not* random, how would a permuted subsample tell you that? In other words, there has to be some kind of trend, a simple land-use regression variable, that would have some non-centrality when the null is false - that is that the "distribution is not random" as you say.

Comment: @Toffee It is likely to be *far* more efficient to stay with gridded data rather than using vector data for this calculation.  Schyler: could you tell us a little more about the research objective, the hypothesis(es) you with to test, and how these animal survey areas were selected?  We need to figure out whether a simple, standard statistical test will do the trick (and save you loads of computing) or whether and to what extent we need to cope with spatial correlation.

Comment: Hi whuber and AdamO, first, thank you for getting back to me, I'll do my best to address your questions! So the point of the study is to determine the difference in land cover representation for a certain citizen science project samples. My hypothesis is that samples will be common in urban areas while less common in agricultural areas. I intersected survey points with 1km grid cells over the study site, and then tabulated the area to get a table of the proportion of land cover types within each grid cell. I did this both for the samples and the entire land cover data set.

Comment: Essentially I want to know if there is a significant difference in the land cover types surveyed, but I want my analysis to be more meaningful than summary stats (eg mean, mode max etc). Thank you all for any input.